# Socket com UTF-8

Tags: java, socket

Estou fazendo um chat que vai rodar em rede (interna), só não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar a questão dos acentos e "ç". Ele funciona executando na IDE mas se eu mandar fazer o .jar e executar (em qualquer PC) ele não funciona os acentos, fica com caracteres estranhos.

**Servidor do Chat**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ServerChatPologis().initServer();
}

private void initServer() {
    try{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORTA_SERVER);

        //Fica esperando um cliente se conectar
        while(true) {
            Socket cliente = server.accept(); //Aguardando

            //Quando o cliente se conectar
            String ipCliente = cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
            System.out.println("Efetuada conexão com o endereço " + ipCliente);

            listaClientes.add(new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream()));
            listaIps.add(ipCliente);

            //Classe que irá tratar o envio de mensagens do cliente
            TrataCliente trataCliente = new TrataCliente(this, cliente.getInputStream(), ipCliente);
            new Thread(trataCliente).start();

        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void mandarMsgParaTodos(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);

    for(PrintStream clientStream : listaClientes) {
        clientStream.println(msg);
    }
}
```

**Classe TrataCliente** (que faz os recebimentos das mensagens e vê oq deve fazer).

```
public class TrataCliente implements Runnable{

    private ServerChatPologis server;
    private InputStream inputClient;
    private String ipCliente;

    public TrataCliente(ServerChatPologis server, InputStream inputClient, String ipCliente) {
        this.server = server;
        this.inputClient = inputClient;
        this.ipCliente = ipCliente;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputClient));

            String msg;
            while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                server.mandarMsgParaTodos(msg);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

}
```

**Tela do Usuario em Swing para o envio e recebimento de Mensagens.**
Essa tela fiz só para por aqui, sei que não ta bem implementada. Mas a real que eu tenho tem os mesmos metodos de envio e recebimento, como está nos códigos. Só não coloquei a outra por estar maior em questão de códigos.

```
public class ChatClientSwing2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Socket cliente;
    private String ipCliente;
    private final String SERVER_ADRESS = "192.168.1.111"; //Aqui na minha rede é usado esse
    private final int PORTA_SERVER = 3225;


    public ChatClientSwing2() {
        initComponents();
        initSocket();
    }

    public void initSocket() {
        try {
            this.cliente = new Socket(SERVER_ADRESS, PORTA_SERVER);
            this.ipCliente = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

            //Cria Thread que irá receber as mensagens
            initRecebeMsg();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initRecebeMsg() {

        //Inicia o recebindo da mensagens
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cliente.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    String msg;

                    //Escreve as mensagens recebidas
                    while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(msg);
                        String msgAnterior = areaMensagens.getText();
                        areaMensagens.setText(msgAnterior + "\n" + msg);
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        areaEnviarMensagem = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        btnEnviar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        areaMensagens = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        areaEnviarMensagem.setColumns(20);
        areaEnviarMensagem.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(areaEnviarMensagem);

        btnEnviar.setText("Enviar");
        btnEnviar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnEnviarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        areaMensagens.setColumns(20);
        areaMensagens.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(areaMensagens);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 322, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnEnviar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 85, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnEnviar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        String msg = areaEnviarMensagem.getText();
        if (msg.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        PrintStream saida = null;
        try {
            saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            saida.println(msg);
            areaEnviarMensagem.setText("");
            areaEnviarMensagem.grabFocus();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClientSwing2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClientSwing2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClientSwing2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClientSwing2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ChatClientSwing2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextArea areaEnviarMensagem;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea areaMensagens;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEnviar;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é no socket que vai a condificação mas no [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/InputStreamReader.html) e no [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), veja o construtor:

```
public InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)
```

No chat cliente você colocou certo, mas na classe TrataCliente faltou o utf8:

```
public void run() {

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputClient, "UTF-8"));

        String msg;
        while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            server.mandarMsgParaTodos(msg);
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Também no botão `btnEnviarActionPerformed` não há o charset especificado, você pode usar esse construtor:

```
private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String msg = areaEnviarMensagem.getText();
    if (msg.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    PrintStream saida = null;
    try {
        saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream(), true, "UTF-8");
        saida.println(msg);
        areaEnviarMensagem.setText("");
        areaEnviarMensagem.grabFocus();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi a parte do Botão, pois não consegui criar esse construtor. Até por quê no primeiro parametro estou tendo que passar um OutputStream que é vem do client (socket).

Comment: Eu realmente estou tentando achar um jeito de fazer do jeito que vc falou mas não achei nada que pudesse fazer funcionar

Comment: Vou tentar ser mais claro

Comment: Não existe um construtor para "saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");", é isso que ele me exibe quando digito o código passado.

Comment: Na documentação do Java 8 que eu coloquei existe, você usa o java 8?

Comment: Sim, mas na documentação passada não tem nada referente a esse construtor, o mais proximo que achei foi "public PrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush, String encoding)", mas também não funcionou :/

Comment: E além disso, executando na IDE funciona até do jeito que postei, mas se for executar pelo .jar gerado, não da, sempre muda os caracteres.

Comment: Usei na realidade esse construtor que te passei, esse sim deu certo! Obrigado!